# Map Azure Blob Storage files to a custom activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a container with 100 binary files. Is there a way to run a custom activity (can be a .net program or, ideally, a container) for each one of these files using Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Answer (score 0):

I created batch account in Azure portal
and created pool in batch account.
Image for reference:

I created pipeline in ADF and I created custom Activity using following details:

[image]

AzureBatch2:

[image]

Here AzureBlobStorage1 is blob storage linked service where bin files are there.
AzureBlobStorage1:

[image]

binaryfile:

[image]

Custom1 Settings:

[image]

I set command as

```
cmd
```

I started debug and it is running successfully.

[image]

Custom Activity created adfjobs folder in binaryfile storage account.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

It is working fine from my end kindly check from your end.